# Laravelのコンポーネントで空白が出力される

Tags: laravel

Laravle7で、コンポーネントによる共通表示部分の出力において、
コンポーネント表示部分の前後に余分な空白が入ってしまいます。

app/Views/Components/SiteTitle.php

```
class SiteTitle extends Component
{

    public $title;
    
    /**
     * Create a new component instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
    $this->title = 'タイトル';
    }

    /**
     * Get the view / contents that represent the component.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\View\View|string
     */
    public function render()
    {
        return view('components.site-title');
    }
}
```

resources/views/components/site-title.blade.php

```
{{$title}}
```

表示するblade

```
<title><x-site-title/></title>
```

簡略化していますが、このような構成でx-site-title部分に
タイトルと表示してほしいのですが、

```
<title> タイトル </title>
```

のように、「タイトル」の前後に空白が表示されます。

この解決法を知っている方いらっしゃいますでしょうか。

Answer (score 0):

解決しなかったので、同じような機能をヘルパーで実装できたのでそちらで対応しました。